# Maven: build another POM as a part of build cycle

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

Our web application uses a database and is currently configured as two *unrelated* Maven projects (kept in different git repositories):

1. The application code (Java), let's call it `app-pom.xml`
2. The database schema `db-pom.xml` - built upon Liquibase changelogs. Liquibase runs as a part of the `deploy` phase.

This worked just fine, but now we're setting up an end-2-end test, which requires a test DB. (Yes I know we could make DB changelogs a part of `app-pom.xml`, but we've chosen this design because there are more applications that use this DB schema).

Is it possible to download `db-pom.xml` and run its `deploy` target as a part of `app-pom.xml`'s build cycle (e.g. during `pre-integration-test`)?

Comment: If you use Jenkins you can add a dependency to db-pom.xml and set it as an upstream project.  If the dependency is a snapshot version it will always build it.  Surely you want to release db-pom.xml and include it as a non snapshop dependency.

Comment: We do use Jenkins, but we also need to be able to run e2e test locally, which is why I'd like to have it as a part of Maven build.

Comment: It sounds like a dependency to me, build it and release it separately.

Comment: It is effectively a dependency, and we do release it separately indeed. But for the sake of e2e test we need to release it in a slightly different way *and* as a part of the integration test phase - that's the challenge I'm after.